# How to allow LocalService to login to a database?

Tags: sql-server, authentication, windows-services, sql-server-2017

Is it possible to allow a service to connect to a database?

```
1> CREATE LOGIN [NT AUTHORITY\LocalService] FROM WINDOWS;
2> GO
Msg 15401, Level 16, State 1, Server MyComputer\MYDBSERVER, Line 1
Windows NT user or group 'NT AUTHORITY\LocalService' not found. Check the name again.
```

Similar results when I try to use SQL Server Management Studio:

[image]

Or if instead of entering the account name I click Search and try to locate the account from there I get this:

[image]

Or this:

[image]

Is it possible to allow a windows service to operate on a database or are services not supposed to touch databases?

Comment: I'm thinking... I've been having similar trouble when I was trying to give LocalService permissions to certain files for similar reasons (my service must be able to operate on these files)... Perhaps this sheds some light on the topic? https://superuser.com/questions/254979/windows-use-local-service-and-or-network-service-account-for-a-windows-service From the answer to this question I linked:

Comment: "*Also the entire point of the NT AUTHORITY\LocalService account is that it has minimum privileges on the system. Giving it more privileged decreases the security of the many services on your system designed to run at the low privilege level it was designed to proffer. If your service requires privileges above and beyond those, you should create a new account for it with the necessary privileges and set that account in the Log On tab of the service's properties.*"

Comment: Maybe it is by design that I cannot add any more permissions to LocalService and if my service needs to access a database / access files in user directories / etc then I must create a new account for this service?

Comment: Although if I'm right then this raises another question namely how to properly add an account for a service since I suppose this is not going to be a regular user account...

Comment: As per [Configure Windows Service Accounts and Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-windows-service-accounts-and-permissions#Appendix) I think you'll find the account name is `NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE`.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Same story. BTW as per [LocalService Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localservice-account) the name of the account is `NT AUTHORITY\LocalService`. So idk.